# dynamic web service calls at runtime

Tags: java, oracle, soap, bpel, business-process-management

i'm new to SOA and i did some readings but i was not able to answer the following :

i want to call some web services in a specific order. the information needed to call each web service and the order of the call are **ONLY** known at **run time** through Database.so the flow would be

1. connect to database to load the information.
2. from the loaded information i will call some web services in the right order with the specific parameters (the order of the parameters are also loaded from database).
   so my question is : can i use BPEL to do that ?

Comment: Looke at UTL_DBWS in oracle, or DII in java

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might be able to use a combination of while and switch.

The number of times your while loop executes and which of the paths under switch executes in each iteration would be determined based on your database call before the while loop.

See:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29597_01/dev.1111/e10224/bp_conditn.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/dev.1111/e10224/bp_conditn.htm#SOASE472